# Is there any built in method in c++ to findout length of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays

like array.length in java is there any built in method in c++ to findout size of an array?

I know about length(). but it only works for strings only ...

And i tried this ...

```
int a[10];
a[0]=1;
a[1]=2;
print(sizeof(a)/size(a[0]))
```

but it gives output as 10 but is there a way getting only 2 as output

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. The array has length `10` not `2`.

Comment: Note that you can't do this in Java, either: if you create a 10-element array, you'll see its size remain 10, even though only two elements are set.

Comment: @jnovacho I don't agree. OP wants a container, which in this case will return 2 - it's *capacity* is 10, but *size* is 2, because he entered only 2 elements to the container. `std::vector` fills these requirements.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using C++, don't use arrays, use `std::vector` instead (especially if you need the *count of currently held items*, not the *container's capacity*). Then you can write:

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.push_back(1);
vec.push_back(2);
printf("%d\n", vec.size());
```

Answer (score 6):

```
int a[10];
```

declares an array of 10 ints; sure, you're only initialising the first two, but the other 8 are still there, they're just (probably) filled with junk at the moment.

To do what you want, you should use a `std::vector` instead. You can then do this:

```
std::vector<int> a;
a.push_back(1);
a.push_back(2);

std::cout << a.size() << std::endl; // prints 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in C/C++ do not store their lengths in memory, so it is impossible to find their size purely given a pointer to an array. Any code using arrays in those languages relies on a constant known size, or a separate variable being passed around that specifies their size.

In an array of 10 ints, when it is declared, memory is allocated for 10 int values. even if you initialize just two, the rest of it contains some junk values and the memory remains allocated.

If you want the used size, your best bet is to use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to know the number of elements in an array you can do this

```
int array[3] = {0, 1, 2};
int arraylength = sizeof(array)/ sizeof(*array);
```

Comment: He already did that. What he asks is: how to determine, how many elements in array were actually initialized by the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. It's name is `vector::size`. It doesn't apply to C-style arrays, only to `std::vector`. Note that Java's `Array` class is also not a C-style array.